# What is the difference between $this->id and $id

Tags: php, this

What is the difference between $this->id and $id.

```
class Test{
 public $id;

 function Test(){
  $this->id = 1;
 }
}
```

===

```
class Test{
 public $id;

 function test(){
  $id = 1;
 }
}
```

how to get the variable from other class?

```
class TestA{
 public $test;

 function TestA(){
  $this->test = new Test();
  echo $this->test->id;
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that you're missing a couple `}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`php` doesn't work in a way `C++`, `Java` and `C#` work.

In php you should **always** use `$this` reference and `->` operator to access the instance variables.

So the first code assigns `1` to the instance `id` property, and in the second you're assigning `1` to a local `$id` variable.

Comment: Also, see the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference on your example, but using `$this->variable_name` can be useful when you have inner variable with the same name within your method:

```
class test{
 public $id;

 function test($id){
  $id = 1;        // method parameter
  $this->id = 2;  // object member
}
```

Comment: `$this->id` is not a class member, but an instance member. It would be a class member if it was static and accessed as `self::$id`

Answer (score 0):

In your samples, there's really no difference. You can alway access member variables also by qualifying it with `$this`, als all member variables belong to `$this`. As MarinJuraszek says, it is important to consider the scope.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->id` refers to a class property it can be accessed in class methods, also via its obect.

`$id` is only a variable that can be  accessed in the local scope where it was created.